# How do I add a promotional message to my posts?

Tags: customization

I'm sure this is a dup, but I honestly can't find an answer.

I'd like to add a message to the start and end of my posts:

```
"Check out my new startup: Facebook For Dogs!"
```

Is there a simple way to do this, hopefully using a plugin?

Comment: If the answer below solves you problem please click on the tick mark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to hook into `the_content` to add a message.

Something like this:

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'wpse51338_filter_content');
/*
 * Filter the content to add a message before and after it.
 */
function wpse51338_filter_content($content)
{
    // not a singular post?  just return the content
    if(!is_singular())
        return $content;

    $msg = sprintf(
        '<p class="special-message">%s</p>',
        __('Here is an awesome message!', 'your_textdomain_string') // this is your message
    );
    return $msg . $content . $msg;
}
```

As a [plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/add-message-to-posts.php).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I should have mentioned I'm a complete newbie. How do I install this plugin?

Comment: you can paste this code in your `functions.php` file ;)